# Emacs-like Ctrl+Up/Down text navigation in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs

In the Windows version of Emacs, Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down navigate between blocks of text by going to the prev/next blank line instead of line by line. Is there a way to reproduce this functionality in Visual Studio?